# Why does transfer learning work?

Tags: neural-networks, transfer-learning

I'd like to know if there is a theoretical/math proof of why transfer learning actually works.

I understand the intuition that transfer learning helps because a given neural network has already learned a good representation that can be used as a "starting point" to a new task(please correct me If I'm wrong), but is there a formal theoretical proof of it?

Any help is appreciated.